# How SubString,Limit Using C?

Tags: c, string, unicode, utf-8, substring

## Section#1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    static const unsigned char text[] = "000ßh123456789";
    int32_t current=1;
    int32_t text_len = strlen(text)-1;
    /////////////////////////////////
    printf("Result : %s\n",text);
    /////////////////////////////////
    printf("Lenght : %d\n",text_len);
    /////////////////////////////////
    printf("Index0 : %c\n",text[0]);
    printf("Index1 : %c\n",text[1]);
    printf("Index2 : %c\n",text[2]);
    printf("Index3 : %c\n",text[3]);//==> why show this `�`?
    printf("Index4 : %c\n",text[4]);//==> why show this `�`?
    printf("Index0 : %c\n",text[5]);
    /////////////////////////////////
    return 0;
}
```

why `text[3]` and `text[4]` show `�`?

how can also support utf-8 character in `Index`?

---

## Section#2

I want write a function like `mb_substr` in php.

`(verybigstring or string)` mb_substr ( `(verybigstring or string)` input , `(verybigint or int)` start [, `(verybigint or int)` $length = NULL ] )

Some Example:

- mb_substr("hello world",0);

  ==>`hello world`
- mb_substr("hello world",1);

  ==>`ello world`
- mb_substr_two("hello world",1,3);

  ==>`el`
- mb_substr("hello world",-3);

  ==>`rld`
- mb_substr_two("hello world",-3,2);

  ==>`rldhe`

### My Question is Section#1

Can anyone help me?(please)

Comment: #1 That doesn't look like an ASCII char. #2 You need to try something yourself. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: in #1, how can get a utf-8 char string as index?

Comment: 1) One question per question! 2) Unclear. 3) We are not a coding/tutoring/consulting service.

Comment: Since your input is encoded using UTF-8 (I presume), your code will need to be UTF-8-aware. Alternative, you can start by "decoding" the UTF-8 bytes into an array of Unicode Code Points (stored in `int32_t` or `uint32_t`), and work with the array. (This requires more memory, but simplifies the problem.)

Comment: my Problem & my question is #1.

Answer (score 1):

The [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character set currently includes more than 128,000 characters (which I shall henceforth call Code Points to avoid confusion) with space reserved for far, far more. As such, a `char` which is only 8 bits in size on modern general-computing machines can't be used to contain a Code Point.

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a way of encoding these Code Points into bytes. The following are the bytes you placed in `text[]` (assuming UTF-8 was used to encode the Code Points) and what they represent:

```
i:             0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
text[i]:    0x30 30 30 C3 9F 68 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 00
              -- -- -- ----- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
Code Point: U+30 30 30    DF 68 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39  0
Graph:         0  0  0     ß  h  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

As you can see, UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding. A single Code Points encodes to a variable number of bytes. This means you can't translate indexes-into-text into indexes-into-array-of-bytes without scanning the array.

A Code Point encoded using UTF-8 starts with

```
0b0xxxxxxx    Represents an entire Code Point
0b110xxxxx    The start of a 2-byte sequence
0b1110xxxx    The start of a 3-byte sequence
0b11110xxx    The start of a 4-byte sequence
```

The only other form of bytes you will encounter in UTF-8 is

```
0b10xxxxxx    A continuation byte (the 2nd, 3rd or 4th byte of sequence)
```

A simple way to find the *n*<sup>th</sup> Code Point in a string (if you assume the input is valid UTF-8) is to search for the *n*<sup>th</sup> `char` for which `(ch & 0xC0) != 0xC0` is true. You can use the same approach to count the number of Code Points in a string.

Comment: Good,I want make Section2, but My Question is Section1, please help me to fix #1.

Comment: I already did. I showed you how to find the start of a Code Point. That means you also know how to find the start of the next Code Point. With that, you have the starting indexes of the Code Point and the length of the Code Point. So all you have to do is print those bytes.

Comment: tank you, i should use `wchar_t` type for string?

Comment: If you want, you can deal with an array of Code Points instead of dealing with UTF-8 by decoding the UTF-8 bytes (stored in `char`) into Code Points (`wchar_t`) and vice-versa on output.

Comment: speed for me is important.